# Can i compile assimp with atomics/pthreads via vcpkg and/or CMake?

Tags: cmake, vcpkg, assimp

I have a C++ CMake Project with Emscripten set up to compile to WebAssembly (on Windows).
I installed Assimp via vcpkg and the wasm32-emscripten.cmake triplet.

As i want to use Assimp with wasm_multithread-Kit (Qt 6.6.2) i get the following error:

`wasm-ld: error: --shared-memory is disallowed by 3DSLoader.cpp.o because it was not compiled with 'atomics' or 'bulk-memory' features.`

But i dont know how to compile it with atomics/pthreads option? I can't enable the option in vcpkg on installing assimp, so I assume is is enabled there. Can i somehow tweak my CmakeLists.txt in my project to achieve this?

I use Qt_6_6_2_multi_threaded-Kit with emscripten-Compiler 3.1.37 for C++.
I installed assimp via
`SET VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET=wasm32-emscripten`
`vcpkg install assimp`

I don't see Options to set in
\vcpkg\ports\assimp\portfile.cmake
which i looked up on
\vcpkg\buildtrees\assimp\src\v5.3.1-c1ad782f20.clean\Build.md

I hope there is another way through CMake to set options, or maybe it is not possible?